# Make site Load Faster

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, compression

I have 8 MB in PNG files but the Problem is that i cant decompress them anymore i tried every png compressor. Maybe thre is also something in the code? Because the site takes damn forever to load. Is there a way i can compress the javascript or html or so?

Just take a look at the sourcecode and maybe its something there i can do to SPEED it up way faster?

Comment: Quick note; might cause some work for you. All photographs should be jpg. I see that you chose png because of the frameborder, but you should have the frame as a second png-file instead.

Comment: @OptimusCrime, You are right & mystycs, always use JPG for photographs  & PNG for vector shapes & transparent images.

Comment: You can use sprites also read this article http://css-tricks.com/158-css-sprites/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's like a zillion http-requests on your page. Try reducing the number of requests by using spritesheets and inlining css and javascript.

I see you are also using images for your menu? Try to use a font for that, with the @font-face directive. (this will also prevent the flash you are seeing, when you hover over the menu-items)

And try to use jpegs (as they allow much better compression for photographs in general) for the slideshow. Use a png for the frameborder to allow for transparency. This would also allow much more flexibility, since you don't have to manually add the frameborder in photoshop, should there be more photos to add to the sideshow.

There's like a ton of other stuff you could do to improve your speed. You should try to conform to some of the best practices in the modern web-industry.

Some useful resources for you:

[Move the Web Forward](http://movethewebforward.org/)

[HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/)

Comment: Also if you can't use a custom font for your navigation menu I would suggest combining the two images you're using for the "hover" effect into one image and then using background-positioning in CSS. That'll get rid of the blinking and you'll have much fewer images to load.

Comment: Here's a great tutorial and explanation of what I'm talking about: http://css-tricks.com/158-css-sprites/

Comment: @DannyCooper that's what I said with the sprites :)

Answer (score 1):

Did you use Photoshop to create your PNGs? If so, did you use File > Save for Web to save the images? That will reduce the size of your PNGs by a ton.

Comment: Yup did that. They are like 300kb a piece

Comment: the images are being scales down in the html.  It's best to save them at the resolution you want to display them at.  Then load the larger img on demand (ajax on click).

Comment: Yes but when you click them they becmoe biggger.

Comment: I might also try creating two PNGs of the picture frame you're using - one horizontal and one vertical, and overlaying your images on top of the frames so you're only loading two PNGs for the gallery instead of one for each photo.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the YSlow addon in Firefox.

YSlow analyses webpages and why they're slow based on Yahoo!'s rules for high performance web sites.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yslow/

Answer (score 1):

Things to do to make your page load faster:

1. Put all `<scripts>` at the end of the `body`  - this
   ensures that initial css and html is rendered before any JavaScripts
   is loaded.
2. Convert you images to jpg. Since your gallery images has no
   transparency, there is no need for png.
3. Resize your gallery images, they are [bigger](http://syndicatebox.com/portfolio/elizabeths/images/gallery-photos/12.png) that than needed
4. Put smaller icons, menu items and other graphics into [sprites](http://css-tricks.com/158-css-sprites/)
5. Use [@font-face](http://sixrevisions.com/css/font-face-guide/) insead of servering text as images
6. Use [css gradients](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) for of gradients in images
7. Compress your JavaScript using tools like [UglifyJs](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS)

Answer (score 0):

Install page speed for Chrome and Firefox, which measures your speed and rates it and gives you suggestions on how to improve your page's speed.

http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/

N.B: You must accept `Experimental Extension Apis` on Chrome and install Firebug for Firefox.

Enjoy!